Can't run Retrofit with MockWebServer using TestScope Jetpack Compose
when i try to call frankfurterApi.convert with test scope, the test instantly gets terminated(println("here2") doesn't get called), but with runBlocking everything works good, just like with viewModelScope in production
test:
private lateinit var mockWebServer: MockWebServer

@Before
fun init() {
    mockWebServer = MockWebServer()
    auth = mockAuth()
    firestore = mockFirestore(listener)
}

@Test
fun requestConversion_success() = runTest {
    val currentBalance = 234f
    val from = CurrencyEnum.EUR
    val to = CurrencyEnum.USD
    val api = Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(mockWebServer.url("/"))
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build().create(FrankfurterApi::class.java)
    val jsonResponse = """
        {
          "amount": $currentBalance,
          "base": "$from",
          "date": "2024-06-12",
          "rates": {
            "$to": 219.3
          }
        }
        """
    mockWebServer.enqueue(MockResponse().setBody(jsonResponse).setResponseCode(200))
    val datastoreManager = mockk<DataStoreManager> {
        every { balanceFlow() } returns flowOf(Pair(from.ordinal, currentBalance))
        every { themeFlow() } returns flowOf()
    }
    val repository = SettingsRepository(auth, firestore.collection("data"), api, datastoreManager)
    val viewModel = SettingsViewModel(repository, CoroutineScopeProvider(this))
    advanceUntilIdle()
    viewModel.changeCurrency(to)
    advanceUntilIdle()
    println(viewModel.uiState.value.currencyChangeResult)
    assertTrue(viewModel.uiState.value.currencyChangeResult is Result.Success)
}

view model:
@HiltViewModel
class SettingsViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val settingsRepository: SettingsRepository,
    scopeProvider: CoroutineScopeProvider
): ViewModel() {

private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(UiState())
private val scope = scopeProvider.provide() ?: viewModelScope
val uiState = _uiState.asStateFlow()

fun changeCurrency(newCurrency: CurrencyEnum) = scope.launch {
    val balance = _uiState.value.balance
    settingsRepository.changeCurrency(balance, newCurrency)
        .catch { updateCurrencyChangeResult(Result.Error(it.message ?: it.toString())) }
        .collect { updateCurrencyChangeResult(it) }
}

scope provider:
class CoroutineScopeProvider(private val coroutineScope: CoroutineScope? = null) {
fun provide() = coroutineScope
}

repository:
class SettingsRepository(
private val auth: FirebaseAuth,
private val firestore: CollectionReference,
private val frankfurterApi: FrankfurterApi,
private val dataStoreManager: DataStoreManager
) {
suspend fun changeCurrency(currentBalance: Balance, newCurrencyEnum: CurrencyEnum) = flow {
    val uid = auth.currentUser?.uid
    if (uid != null) {
        emit(Result.InProgress)
        println("here")
        val convertedMainBalance = frankfurterApi.convert(
                amount = currentBalance.balance,
                from = CurrencyEnum.entries[currentBalance.currency].name,
                to = newCurrencyEnum.name)
        println("here2")
        firestore.document(uid).collection("balance").document("balance")
            .set(Balance(newCurrencyEnum.ordinal, 
convertedMainBalance.rates[newCurrencyEnum.name]!!)).await()
        changeLastTimeUpdated(Instant.now().toEpochMilli())
        emit(Result.Success(""))
    }
}

api:
interface FrankfurterApi {
@GET("latest")
suspend fun convert(
    @Query("amount") amount: Float,
    @Query("from") from: String,
    @Query("to") to: String
): ExchangeCurrency

